# ROS2 diff between node and component

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

what is the difference between node and component?
As per my understanding and demo example of composition, component is also similar to node.

I also tried the simple example to add simple node(which has been created in class and loaded compile time) in the executor.
But I am not able to understand the advantage of component over node?

Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313001/ros2-diff-between-node-and-component/) by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2019-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is still unfortunately still under some active development (see: https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/160) and so not everything is clearly defined yet. I've proposed some terminology that should hopefully be clearer in this document (though I don't know if in the end it will change further):

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/wjwwood/components_wip/rclcpp_components/doc/source/architecture.rst#terminology

Here's a summary of the terminology:

- Node: an instance of `rclcpp::Node` or an instance of a class derived from `rclcpp::Node` (often user defined)
- Composable Node: A Node, which has been built in a certain way and registered at build time as a composable node, which enables it to be instantiated at runtime by a standard executable
- Composable Node Container: a program that can on demand: lookup a node, load (with dlopen) the node's `.so`, instantiate an instance of the node, and then execute the node

---

The contents of the `composition` package and the associated tutorials are useful to see how some of the underlying mechanics work, but it's more of a tech demo and so doesn't have as much infrastructure around it as we'd like.

In the meantime, I'd suggest following the changes happening at https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/160 and waiting for that to finish, or if you need something sooner, try to adapt the examples in the `composition` demo to meet your needs.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1